# looking for deeper understanding of the html form action attribute

Tags: html, forms, action

I am looking for a deeper explanation of the html form action attribute than is usually given. What is really happening when the user hits 'submit' in the browser? I assume that the browser sends some kind of message to the web server software. So the browser is communicating with for instance Nginx.

But the way people talk about the action attribute makes it sound as if the browser is really sending the data to some arbitrary URL. Like to a php script located at that URL, but that doesn't really make sense to me. Is the form data really being sent to the web server and then the web server parses the action attribute and attempts to somehow submit the parameters and values to a script located there? In that case the URL specified by the action attribute would really be more like a suggestion to the web server.

Can someone explain to me what is really going on? I find the idea of the form data being sent to a 'where' or anything other than to the web server quite confusing and I have not been able to find a deeper explanation anywhere. All paths seem to lead to the concept of the form data being sent to some URL as if that actually made sense.

Comment: The browser parse the url in the action attribute and sends the form data to that url

Comment: Can you unpack that with a low level explanation? What is the browser doing specifically? How does it 'send' the data to a URL? Let's say there is a a parameter called "number" with a value of "1". The word 'send' just doesn't make sense to me in this context. Can you explain it without using that word?